# Do school spelling tests increase reading or writing performance of students?

Tags: education, linguistics

Elementary schools across the US often give weekly [spelling lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_test) that the students will be tested on at the end of the week.

Clearly schools believe having kids learn to spell these words helps them with reading and/or writing if they keep doing it.

Does the evidence support this?

Comment: Discussion about whether this question is notable has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132034/discussion-on-question-by-dsollen-do-school-spelling-tests-increasing-reading-or). Do not extend that discussion here.

Comment: One way it could be improved for example is by linking to specific justification for a spelling curriculum ( eg https://www.k12reader.com/spelling-curriculum-design/ ) and specifically indicate which claims they are skeptical about.

Comment: isn't this self-evident? it's hard to write a word if you don't know how to spell it.  if you grade writing performance as correctly writing words, then how could proper spelling not improve results?

Comment: @dandavis, no, it is not self-evident.  As a counter-example, the vast majority of my spelling skill comes from reading everything I could get my hands on -- if spelling lists were a significant contribution, my written vocabulary would be much smaller, at a maximum of 4000 words.

Comment: Why single out spelling?  We could ask: Do school tests in any subject increase student performance?  If not, maybe they are designed to **measure** student performance, rather than to **increase** it.

Comment: @GEdgar mostly due to how frequent they are.  New words each week, tested at the end of the week, is different then spending a month on a topic and then testing how one retained it.

Comment: @dsollen I think I once read a paper proving that frequent repeated testing with quick feedback improved long-term retention; how often these spelling tests reuse words?

Comment: @danila never for my school, or my 'little brother' (from BBBS), I assume that's true across the board but I have no evidence of that.